# How to handle Full Text Search Index across multiple languages in a single table?

Tags: postgresql, full-text-search

I have a table in **Postgres** where I store articles for multiple languages. For a full-text search, I have a separate column that is enabled for full-text search using GIN indexes. Depending on the article language, I store the corresponding body for the corresponding dictionary: German, English, Spanish etc

However, when I want to query the database, it makes a significant difference for which dictionary I search. Actually, I want to query all languages and not only specific ones. So I am curious about how I can achieve that.

This is my table:

```
create table if not exists public.article
(
    id                        serial constraint "pk_article_id" primary key,
    title                     varchar(1024),
    body                      text,
    lang                      varchar(2),
    fts_dict                  regconfig generated always as (
                                  CASE
                                      WHEN ((lang)::text = 'en'::text) THEN 'english'::regconfig
                                      WHEN ((lang)::text = 'de'::text) THEN 'german'::regconfig
                                      WHEN ((lang)::text = 'es'::text) THEN 'spanish'::regconfig
                                      ELSE 'simple'::regconfig
                                      END) stored,
    fts_body                  tsvector generated always as (
                                  CASE
                                      WHEN ((lang)::text = 'en'::text) THEN to_tsvector('english'::regconfig, body)
                                      WHEN ((lang)::text = 'de'::text) THEN to_tsvector('german'::regconfig, body)
                                      WHEN ((lang)::text = 'es'::text) THEN to_tsvector('spanish'::regconfig, body)
                                      ELSE to_tsvector('simple'::regconfig, body)
                                      END) stored
);
```

And here comes the GIN-Index:

```
create index if not exists idx_article_fts_body
    on public.article using gin (fts_body);
```

So this table contains article in several languages. I have an auto-generated column that stores the body as `tsvector` in its specific dictionary, depending on the original language.

While searching for articles, I come across, that the dictionary matters heavily:

```
SELECT a.id, a.lang, a.title, a.body
FROM article a
         INNER JOIN summaries s ON a.id = s.article_id
WHERE a.fts_body @@ plainto_tsquery('german', 'Grünheide')
```

delivers only all articles with a german locale, but not the english or spanish articles containing 'Grünheide'.

If I want to include all english or spanish articles, that contain the same word "grünheide", I need to query for the corresponding dictionary additionally:

```
SELECT a.id, a.lang, a.title, a.body
FROM article a
         INNER JOIN summaries s ON a.id = s.article_id
WHERE a.fts_body @@ plainto_tsquery('english', 'Grünheide')

SELECT a.id, a.lang, a.title, a.body
FROM article a
         INNER JOIN summaries s ON a.id = s.article_id
WHERE a.fts_body @@ plainto_tsquery('spanish', 'Grünheide')
```

Omitting the dictionary in the query seems to default to "simple" or "english", which makes the result similar to if I had asked for "english".

My question is: do I really need to iterate over all dictionary-types (languages) and re-query again and again to get the full list of all articles that contains a specific term?

Or is there any other technique I should know?

Comment: Of course the configuration matters.  Otherwise, what would be the point of having them?  If you don't care about stemming and stopwords and normalization, then you can just use 'simple' for all and it will work regardless of language.  If you do care about those things, then you need to process the query with the same configuration of the things you hope to find.  You could just iterate through all of them, or you could simply ask the user what language they are searching in.

Answer (score 0):

You must use the same language in the query as for the ts_vector

```sql
SELECT a.id, a.lang, a.title, a.body
FROM article a
         INNER JOIN summaries s ON a.id = s.article_id
WHERE a.fts_body @@ plainto_tsquery(a.fts_dict, 'Grünheide')
```

Comment: thanks, I tried this before. But this query is never using the GIN index according to "explain analyze".